# Understanding gunicorn and Django

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm trying to understand how gunicorn works with Django.

The docs on [Running Django in Gunicorn as a generic WSGI application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/#running-django-in-gunicorn-as-a-generic-wsgi-application) say:

```
At its simplest, gunicorn just needs to be called with the location
of a module containing a WSGI application object named application.
```

So you can do:

```
$ gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

And it will run. But what exactly is this doing? I am looking in the root of my Django project, but there is no file called `myproject.wsgi` there. So what is behind the magic?

The [docs also say](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#django) that:

```
Gunicorn will look for a WSGI callable named application if not specified.
```

What does this mean? What is "application" in the context of my Django app? Should I specify it as the name of my Django app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a wsgi.py file at the root of your django project (created with django-admin startproject myproject).

This wsgi.py has the `application` callable:

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: The file is not at the root of the project, but inside the main app (which has the save name as the project itself).